# ¿ Como mostrar los resultados de una consulta en ajax y Jquery en formato tabla?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Con el código que se indica se analiza un archivo previamente seleccionado y se llama a una API que devuelve los datos de un análisis, mostrándolos de forma encadenada en una fila. Lo que pretendo es mostrarlos en varias columnas y una fila o viceversa, es decir en un tabla.

```js
<script>
$(function(){
        $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var f = $(this);
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.ibpindex.com/api/",  
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false
            })
                 .done(function(javascript_json){
                    weobtain = 
            '# IBP: ' + '  '+ javascript_json['hiking']['ibp'] + '  '+
       '# Distancia total (Km): ' + '  '+ javascript_json['hiking']['totlengthkm'] + '  ' +
 '# Desnivel (+) acumulado (m): ' + '  '+ javascript_json['hiking']['accuclimb'] + '  ' +
 '# Desnivel (-) acumulado (m): ' + '  '+ javascript_json['hiking']['accudescent'] 
                    document.getElementById('obtain').innerHTML = weobtain;
                });
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="formuploadajax" method="post">
        API key: <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="yourapikey" value="yourapikey">
        <br /><br />
        <input  type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload file"/>
    </form><br />
    <div id="obtain"></div>
    
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hola MAC, que error te arroja la consola o que es lo que no esta funcionando?

Answer (score 1):

Te diré que intentes evitar los br en tu código html, aquí te dejo como hacer lo que pides.

**EJEMPLO:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // var f = $(this);
/*    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://www.ibpindex.com/api/",
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      enctype: "multipart/form-data";
      data: formData,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false
    });
  });*/
  document.getElementById('obtain').innerHTML = `<table>
    <tr>
      <th>IBP</th>
      <th>Distancia total</th>
      <th>Desnivel acomulado</th>
      <th>Desnivel acomulado</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10 mg</td>
      <td>26 km</td>
      <td>(+) 12,54 </td>
      <td>(-) 10,26</td>
    </tr>
  </table>`;
  });
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  margin: 10px;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
  height: max-content;
}

td {
  width: 80px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 2px solid;
}
```

```html
<form id="formuploadajax" method="post">
  <p>API key: <input type="text" name="key" placeholder="yourapikey" value="yourapikey"></p>
  <input type="file" id="file" name="file" />
  <input type="submit" value="Upload file" />
</form>

<div id="obtain"></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Gracias @Daniel, eso es lo que pretendía conseguir, no obstante el código parece funcionar bien si se ejecuta desde la consola (me refiero dando al botón ejecutar in-situ), sin embargo al montarlo en la web, no me muestra la tabla con los valores fijos.  He probado y no hay manera. Por otro lado, veo que has asteriscado parte del código que trae los valores que quiero que se inserten en los tabla, por ejemplo en <td>10 mg</td><td>26 km</td> aquí deben de aparecer los valores de la variable "weobtain" de mi código, supongo que seria algo así ...

Comment: .. <td>'+ javascript_json['hiking']['ibp'] + '</td> y así sucesivamente.

Comment: si quieres que los datos se mantengan al recargar la página, debes de usar localstorage o un base de datos para mantener la información que deseas, al usar localstorage, para guardar algún dato, tienes que hacer esto: `localstorage.setItem("key", "value")`, para obtener esa información : `localstorage.getItem("key")`

Comment: Creo que no me has entendido o no me he explicado bien. No quiero mantener los datos al refrescar la pagina ni guardarlos en una BBDD. Si te fijas en el código de referencia de la pregunta, los valores los traigo bien, lo que pasa es que los concatena en una línea  y lo que quiero es que los saque en una tabla, que puede ser la que tu me pones.

Comment: entonces, tú quieres enviar los datos que entran a un archivo que analizará esos datos para crear una tabla y esos datos quieres mostrar en pantalla?

Comment: ¡¡ Eso es!!. En el input del formulario se envía una Key para acceder a la API la cual analizará el archivo que se envía. Una vez analizado devuelve los resultados y esos resultados son los que quiero mostrar en pantalla en formato tabla, lo que pasa que me los muestra en una línea , uno a continuación del otro y lo que pretendo es  que quede en una tabla, similar a la solución que me dabas.

Answer (score 0):

Despues de investigar he dado con la solución que pretendía obtener. Los datos se presentan una vez analizados por la API en formato tabla similar a como comentaba @Daniel pero respetando la codificación inicial y modificando la estructura y la ubicación de las etiquetas de la tabla. Ahora la presentación queda en columnas y en una fila, pero también fácilmente se puede cambiar la estructura conmutando las etiquetas entre si, ahora se quedaría una columna y varias filas. Dejo solo el código del script por si le sirve a alguien más.

```js
<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#formuploadajax").on("submit", function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var f = $(this);
            var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("formuploadajax"));
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.ibpindex.com/api/",  
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                data: formData,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
            processData: false
            })
               .done(function(javascript_json){                 
    weobtain = 
            "<table>"
              +"<tr>"
                  +"<th>"+"IBP"+"</th>"
                  +"<th>"+'Distancia total'+"</th>"
                  +"<th>"+'Desnivel acumulado'+"</th>"
              +"</tr>"
              +"<tr>"
                 +"<td>"+javascript_json['hiking']['ibp']+"</td>" 
                 +"<td>"+javascript_json['hiking']['analyzedlengthkm']+"</td>" 
                 +"<td>"+javascript_json['hiking']['totlengthkm']+"</td>" 
              +"</tr>"
           +"</table>" 
               document.getElementById('obtain').innerHTML = weobtain;
             });
        });
    });
</script>
```